# Why am I getting an output of always 1 in the below code

Tags: c, variables, reference

I was writting a program to assign the Value of N to M in the declaration statement.If i gave value of N in declaration i get the same value in output.But if i read from user ,i am getting 1 always

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{ clrscr();
 int N,M=N;    
 scanf("%d",&N); 
 printf("%d",M);  
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: why is this tagged as python?

Comment: Please explain why you expect `M` to have the value of `1`. At the time that `M=N` is executed, `N` does not yet have a value of `1`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not put irrelevant tags on your question. If you are hoping to get more people to notice the question, keep in mind that they will not be happy about it.

Comment: That is my doubt or something which i dont know,why M is assigned a value 1  when N does not have a value.Is it by default for every variable.But there is no error if i wrote M=N outside declaration

Comment: @rv.kvtch because the platform keep asking me to put 5 tags and i was short  of tags

Comment: `the platform keep asking me to put 5 tags` No. The platform asks for 5 tags **maximum**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`N` is *uninitialised* meaning `N` could have **any** integer value. That unknown value is copied to `M`, and then `scanf()` called to assign a value to `N`.

The program needs to verify that system calls (like `scanf()`) has done what was expected with user input.

Below is a "better" version that tries to protect itself to an extent.

```
int main() { // it's okay to use whitespace to enhance readability.
    int N, M;
    if( scanf( "%d", &N ) != 1 )
        printf( "scanf didn't assign a value!\n" );

    M = N;

    printf( "%d\n", M );

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Notice what happens when a user does something unexpected. This is the output

```
fifteen
scanf didn't assign a value!
22
```

ALWAYS validate user input before using it.

Comment: Thank you but i still have one doubt left and that is if an uniniatialised  variable can have anyunkown value why i am getting always 1 as the output

Comment: @BhagatSingh Uninitialized means it could be **any** value that happens to be in those bytes... Your compiler happens to arrange things so that your 'N' has the value 1. My compiler may do something different. This is the effect of "undefined behaviour". No one can say what random (or not) value will appear when an uninitialized variable is "read". "Uninitialsed" does not mean "a different random number every time."

Comment: Ok thank you for taking your time to answer,now i understand fully

Comment: Ok ,i tick the correct symbol but i couldnt click upvote as i need 15 reputation

Comment: @BhagatSingh I appreciate the 'tick of acceptance'... Best wishes on your learning :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the value of N to M, N does not have any value, that is why you are always getting one. You need to assign the value after getting it from the user.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{ clrscr();
 int N,M;    
 scanf("%d",&N);
 M=N; 
 printf("%d",M);  
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your answer, you stated the following: `"N does not have any value"` -- The formulation of this statement is technically not accurate. The variable `N` always has a value during its entire lifetime, but its value is [indeterminate](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.19.2) until `scanf` is called.

Comment: Sir if i assign a value of a variable(before reading from user as in int N,M=N;) to another variable ,will it assign a default of 1 and if you know further please explain a little bit in detail.I am a beginner so i dont much about the errors that i came up with.

Comment: @BhagatSingh As Andreas Wenzel corrected, whenever you create a new variable, there is indeterminate value declared to that variable